# Find interpolation factor or "progress" within parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a parallelogram with points $A, B, C, D$, and a chosen starting side, $CD$, imagine I'd like to fill this shape with a linear gradient and need to know the normalized "progress" of a given point. That is, given $L$ perpendicular to $CD$ and $AB$, what is the $0 → 1$ value that represents how far along the point $P$ is within the shape?

The points $A, B, C, D, P$ are all that is known and they are expressed as vectors in 2D. The desired answer is a function that takes these inputs and returns a $0 → 1$ value representing how close P is to side $AB$ (or, how far it is from $CD$).

[image]

Comment: Your picture suggests that $L$ is parallel to $AD$, which would make the parallelogram a rectangle. If not, then some of the lines $L$ won't meet the opposite side. What are the input data? What is the source of the question? Please clarify.

Comment: If your line $L$ has intersection point $L_1$ with side $CD$ and intersection point $L_2$ with side $AB$, then $\frac {|L_1P|} {|L_1L_2|}$ is a real number going from $0$ to $1$ when $P$ goes from side $CD$ to side $AB$. Where $|L_1P|$ is distance between the two points. Perhaps you are looking for something that is expressed in a coordinate system? Then, which system? Please clarify.

Comment: Ignore L, all we know is that point P lies somewhere within the parallelogram. We do not know its intersection point with either side (that's probably what we need to derive?). The source of the question is I'd like to perform a gradient fill of this shape, where the fill lines are parallel to sides AB and CD.

Comment: Added some clarifying edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $A$ for the point, $\vec A$ for the vector $\vec {OA}$, $AB$ for the line containing $A$ and $B$, and $\vec {AB}$ for the vector from $A$ to $B$.

We change the basis of the plane, using a basis with origin on $C$, and base vectors $\vec {CD}$ and $\vec {CB}$. We'll call our current basis $\mathcal{B_1}$ and the new one $\mathcal{B_2}$.
In this new basis $\mathcal{B_2}$, point $C$ will have coordinates $(0,0)$, point $D$ $(0,1)$, point $B$ $(1,0)$, point $A$ $(1,1)$. This means the second coordinate is the $0 \to 1$ value we want (and the first coordinate is a $0 \to 1$ value growing in the direction of $CD$ from $CB$ to $DA$).

Putting vectors $\vec {CD}$ and $\vec {CB}$ in two columns gives us a matrix $M$ that allows transforming coordinates of vectors in basis $\mathcal{B_2}$ to $\mathcal{B_1}$. We actually want the reverse transformation, from $\mathcal{B_1}$ to $\mathcal{B_1}$, so we need to invert $M$.

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
x_D-x_C & x_B-x_C \\
y_D-y_C & y_B-y_C
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
r & s \\
t & u
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then $M^{-1} = \frac 1 {\large{ru-st}} \begin{pmatrix}
u & -s \\
-t & r
\end{pmatrix}$

If $P$ has coordinates $(x_P, y_P)$ in $\mathcal{B_1}$, its coordinates in $\mathcal{B_2}$ are
$M^{-1}\vec{CP} = \frac 1 {\large{ru-st}} \begin{pmatrix}
u & -s \\
-t & r
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_P-x_C \\
y_P-y_C
\end{pmatrix}$

So the value we seek is
$\frac 1 {\large{ru-st}} (-t(x_P-x_C)+r(y_P-y_C))$
$= \large {\frac {-(y_D-y_C)(x_P-x_C)+(x_D-x_C)(y_P-y_C)} {(x_D-x_C)(y_B-y_C)-(x_B-x_C)(y_D-y_C)}}$

As a check, we see this expression is $0$ for $P=C$ or $P=D$, and $1$ for $P=B$.
For $P=A$, the value is also $1$ if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram: in which case $-(y_D-y_C)(x_A-x_C)+(x_D-x_C)(y_A-y_C) = -(y_D-y_C)(x_B-x_C)+(x_D-x_C)(y_B-y_C)$
(That's because the difference is $-(y_D-y_C)(x_A-x_B)+(x_D-x_C)(y_A-y_B)$, and $x_A-x_B=x_C-x_D$, $y_A-y_B=y_C-y_D$, so the difference is null).

As the expression is affine in $(x_P,y_P)$ and has the right values on $A, B, C, D$, this confirms it is what we want.

Comment: I see with have had synchroneous answers, but with different approaches.

Comment: This looks right but, when I plug in some sample points, is not normalized 0 → 1. For example defining A,B,C,D as:

(2.061678, 3.332111),
(5.164222, 1.780839),
(6.813322, 2.605389),
(3.710778, 4.156661)

and P as (4.50, 2.66), I get 5.743114 as the interpolant, even though the point is near the middle of the parallelogram so I'd expect something closer to 0.5. So I guess there's a second part: how do I normalize the resulting values?

Comment: @Charlie There is no second part, that should already be normalised. I'll look at your example when I'll be at home.

Comment: @Charlie The formula is right. Your example: $\large {\frac {-(y_D-y_C)(x_P-x_C)+(x_D-x_C)(y_P-y_C)} {(x_D-x_C)(y_B-y_C)-(x_B-x_C)(y_D-y_C)}}$ $= \large {\frac {-(4.156661-2.605389)(4.50-6.813322)+(3.710778-6.813322)(2.66-2.605389)} {(3.710778-6.813322)(1.780839-2.605389)-(5.164222-6.813322)(4.156661-2.605389)}}$ $= 0.66827$. Which seems OK with the diagram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%282.061678%2C+3.332111%29%2C+%285.164222%2C+1.780839%29%2C+%286.813322%2C+2.605389%29%2C+%283.710778%2C+4.156661%29%2C+%284.50%2C+2.66%29

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, very strange we posted our answers at the very same minute. Perhaps this is because we are both French and have the same work habits. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think [**bilinear interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is a good way to manage the positionning of point $P$ within a general quadrilateral (not only a parallelogram) using 2 parameters.

Bilinear interpolation describes any point $P$ inside quadrilateral $ABCD$ in a unique way under the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_P\\y_P\end{pmatrix}=
\color{red}{(1-u)(1-v)}\begin{pmatrix}x_A\\y_A\end{pmatrix}+\color{red}{u(1-v)}\begin{pmatrix}x_B\\y_B\end{pmatrix}+\color{red}{(1-u)v}\begin{pmatrix}x_D\\y_D\end{pmatrix}+
\color{red}{uv}\begin{pmatrix}x_C\\y_C\end{pmatrix}$$

with $0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 1$.

Otherwise said :

$$\begin{cases}x_P&=&
(1-u)(1-v) x_A+u(1-v) x_B+(1-u)v x_D+
uv x_C\\
y_P&=&
(1-u)(1-v) y_A+u(1-v) y_B+(1-u)v y_D+
uv y_C\end{cases}$$

$u$ and $v$ play the rôle of coordinates.

For example taking $u=0,v=0$, one gets $P=A$ ; taking $u=1,v=0$ one gets $P=B$ ; etc.

Comment: This expresses P in terms of u,v, but I already know P and want the inverse: u,v expressed in terms of P, A, B, C, D.

Comment: Therefore, these 2 unknowns (u,v) are solutions to the system of 2 equations $\begin{cases}x_P=... \\ y_P=... \end{cases}$ obtained by replacing all the letters $x_P,y_P,x_A, y_A, ...$ by their values.

Comment: Right, I know how to do it, it's just that you've left the answer as an exercise to the reader. ;)

Comment: No, in fact, it wasn't clear for me that $P$ was known beforehand...

Comment: > The points ,,,, are all that is known and they are expressed as vectors in 2D. The desired answer is a function that takes these inputs and returns a 0→1 value representing how close P is to side  (or, how far it is from ).